# How do I generate a matrix with x dimension and a vector and without using loops? Python

Tags: python, loops, numpy, matrix

Good morning to all.
I want to generate an array for example with 10 columns and 100 rows with the vector `a = np.arange (1,1001)`, but I do not want to use loop since my web page gets saturated if I put a loop.
Someone knows of some numpy or math command or another.

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Just `reshape`?

Comment: Thank you very much Divakar :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a = np.arange(1000).reshape(100, 10)` should do it.

Comment: Thank you very much  Tom Wyllie :)

Comment: And if I want to sort by columns or by rows the vector? you know?